Feature Branch Needs to Be Split Into 2 Unique Feature Branches But Commits Are Not Distinct
I have branch cool-new-feature that is going to be in the works for a few months. While working on this new feature I also refactored a large number of files. The refactored code is used throughout the project and can be utilized independently of the new feature I am working on. The new feature relies on the refactor BUT the refactor does not rely on the new feature. The issue is that I need the refactored files now for other new features and cannot wait until cool-new-feature branch makes its way into main. The refactored files will make their way into our main branch long before the cool-new-feature branch will.
I figured I can just create 2 new branches and manually copy over the changes into the separate branches, but I was wondering if there was an easier way.
My Idea:

Cut a new branch from cool-new-feature called refactor-only.
Delete all files related to the new feature.
Cut a branch from refactor-only called cool-new-feature-restored and use git to restore the deleted files related to the new feature and continue working from there on the new feature.
Now I have a branch that does not have the feature files but has the refactor which can be used in other new features. I also am thinking this will prevent merge problems down the line because git main knows the files were deleted, but also knows that they should be restored when cool-new-feature-restored finally makes its way into main.

My reasoning behind doing it this way is so that my feature branch and others can utilize the refactor immediately without polluting main with the unfinished feature files and eventually when the new feature is complete git will see that the feature files were restored after deletion in cool-new-feature-restored and the deleted files will merge back into main without an issue.
**Are there any negative implications to doing it this way? ** I am mostly worried about deleting the feature files from refactor-only and the features files not being merged in later down the line when this feature is actually completed.
Possible Solution:
I have thought about splitting cool-new-feature into two branches using re-base or cherry-pick but I don't believe I can do this because many of my commits on cool-new-feature involve changes from the refactor and the new feature so I can't just grab the commits I need without bringing in the new feature and the refactor together.

How are the commits in your branch ordered? Do you first do all refactoring commits and only then the feature work or are the interspersed? Or do some commits both refactor and add feature code? Are you will to rebase/rewrite your branch to make it easier to extract the refactoring?

@knittl the refactoring and feature work are intertwined on many of the same commits. So I don't think pulling certain commits out will work. I had to do the refactoring to make the new feature work, so I decided to just merge the refactoring and feature work together into master.

Then Git cannot really support you. Copy over the refactored files or merge and partially revert. Maybe cherry-pick individual commits. Better to structure your branches in a way that makes it easy to merge parts of it.
